# Angular2 api controller call from ts service file

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-apicontroller

i have two solutions
1. ASP.NET web application(.Net framework)(Web Api)
2. ASP.NET Core application(.Net Core)

in Visula Studio 17.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from 
'@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Employee } from '../models/Employee'

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeManagementService {
constructor(private http: Http) {
 }    
}

addEmployeeDetails(employeeDetails: Employee) {

    var obj = {Firstname: employeeDetails.FirstName, LastName: employeeDetails.LastName, PhoneNumber: employeeDetails.PhoneNumber};

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headers });

    let emp = JSON.stringify(obj);

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:xyz/api/employee-management/create-employee', emp, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .toPromise();
```

APIController

```
public class EmployeeManagementApiController : ApiController
 {
    //Create Employee
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/employee-management/create-employee")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateEmployee([FromBody]Employee emp)
    {
        EmployeeService service = new EmployeeService();
        var serv = service.CreateEmployee(emp);

        if (serv.status == 1)
        {
            return Ok(emp);
        }
        else
            return new ResponseMessageResult(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed, serv.message));
    }
}
```

Employee.ts file

```
export class Employee {
FirstName: string;
LastName: string;
PhoneNumber: string;
}
```

Api Employee class file

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

My html file

```
<div class="row">
    <app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <br /><br />
        <h3 style="padding-left:20px;color: #6699CC;font-family:'Bookman Old Style'"><u>Employee Management</u></h3>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>
                <em style="color: red">*</em> First Name:
            </h4>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" [(ngModel)]="emp.FirstName" placeholder="Enter Name" /><br />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>
                <em style="color: red">*</em>Last Name
            </h4>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" [(ngModel)]="emp.LastName" placeholder="Enter Name" /><br />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>
                <em style="color: red">*</em>Phone Number
            </h4>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input" [(ngModel)]="emp.PhoneNumber" placeholder="Enter Name" />
             <br /><br />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12" align="left">

            <button style="color:white" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addEmployee(emp)">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="clearEmployee()">Clear</button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Add component

```
import { Employee } from '../../models/Employee';
import { EmployeeManagementService } from '../../services/employee-
managment.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
selector: 'emp-add',
templateUrl: './employee-add.component.html'
})
export class AddEmployeeComponent {
 emp;
 constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeManagementService) {
    this.emp = new Employee();
 }


addEmployee(emp) {
    this.employeeService.addEmployeeDetails(emp);
    this.clearEmployee(emp);
}
```

My ts file is in on solution and my api is in another solution.
here am getting calls to my API but emp values are all null. Am i missing anything . Please help me out.

same code i have tried with normal controller in same Solution ,
if i send single parameter values is passed to API controller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you use `addEmployeeDetails`?

Comment: import { Employee } from '../../models/Employee';
import { EmployeeManagementService } from '../../services/employee-managment.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'emp-add',
    templateUrl: './employee-add.component.html'
})
export class AddEmployeeComponent {
    emp;
    constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeManagementService) {
        this.emp = new Employee();
    }


    addEmployee(emp) {
        this.employeeService.addEmployeeDetails(emp);
        this.clearEmployee(emp);
    }

Comment: <button style="color:white" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addEmployee(emp)">Submit</button>

Answer (score 1):

Observables are by default "cold" you need to subscribe to them, in order to fire them

```
this.employeeService.addEmployeeDetails(emp).subscribe((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
});
```

In your case, if you use .toPromise() you should use `then`

```
this.employeeService.addEmployeeDetails(emp).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
});
```

Check your network tab to see if you are actually making the request:
[image]

In your network tab when you click your button you should see a post request.

Then check your request:[image]

Link of the plunker I used: http://plnkr.co/edit/HR8l5kYlar4XxmgxLa9Z?p=preview

Comment: Sorry i think you havent understood my question here am sending my obj as emp  "return this.http.post('http://localhost:xyz/api/employee-management/create-employee', emp, options)" here whatever the values am sending like firstname those values are shown null in my API i mean those values are set to null when i debug in my APIController

Comment: @GurramNavyasri what does your `addEmployeeDetails` method return?

Comment: Whatever the values am sending the same values are returned back, but here it doesnt matter i dont bother about what values it returns but what i am sending those values should be presnent right, but here it doesnt

Comment: @GurramNavyasri You are not answering my question. What does your `addEmployeeDetails` method return inside your code? Can you look to your question and tell me?

Comment: But what am asking is not returning values

Comment: @GurramNavyasri no that is the parameter/input of your `addEmployeeDetails` method. Don't you see that your method returns a `Promise`? Do you know what a `Promise` is?

Comment: here public IHttpActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee emp), my emp values are null i am sending FirstName="XYZ" , LastName="Hello" and PhoneNumber="8547857854" Id=all zeros but when coming to CrestaeEmployee method my emp values are FirstName=null, Lastname=null, PhoneNumber=null

Comment: @GurramNavyasri I have answered your question.. Have you even tried implementing it? And you've answered none of my questions..

Comment: Kindly please understand what my question is am i asking about what values are returned ? I am asking why my values became null when Called to my APIController which is in another Solution.

Comment: echonax kindly please understand what you are answering me is not what i am questioning

Comment: @GurramNavyasri where do you fill `this.emp = new Employee();` ? Is it inside the html?

Comment: this.emp = new Employee(); this is inside a typescript file

Comment: @GurramNavyasri but where do you set the properties of it? `FirstName`, `LastName`?

Comment: @GurramNavyasri ok that's good so when you click the button for `addEmployee(emp)` what does `addEmployee(emp) {console.log(emp);` print?

Comment: {"Firstname":"John","LastName":"David","PhoneNumber":"8547854785"}

Comment: @GurramNavyasri and your `let emp = JSON.stringify(obj);` ? Does it print the thing you want when you console.log it just before the http.post?

Comment: echonax Yes it does print the data which i am sending

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of your developer tools if you are actually sending the request? If you are using chrome press F12 and choose the network tab in the upper corner.

Comment: I have seen Network tab in google chrome but sorry i dont understand what you are trying to explain me

Comment: @GurramNavyasri when you click your button, you are making an http.post request. It should be on that network tab if you are actually making the request. As request and response. I'll try to add a picture

Comment: Sorry i dont understand. But can i ask a question. i have tried the same code within the appilcation with normal API call and it worked fine. But why it is not working when i use APIController and that too in another solution?

Comment: @GurramNavyasri I've updated my question. Check the plunker along with the screenshot.

Comment: I can see my request call in network tab and my api is also called but my values are null in API this is what my problem is

Comment: @GurramNavyasri ok can you check your request then in the network tab? I'll put a screenshot again then you put a screenshot of it in your question ok?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't upload my image file

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:xyz/api/employee-management/create-employee
Request Method:POST
Status Code:412 Precondition Failed
Remote Address:[::1]:45310
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:26
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 16 May 2017 10:52:08 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcTmF2eWFzcmkgR3VycmFtIEZpbGVzXEFuZ3VsYXIyXE15Q29kZVxFbXBsb3llZU1hbmFnZW1lbnRBcGlTZXJ2aWNlXEVtcGxveWVlTWFuYWdlbWVudEFwaVNlcnZpY2VcYXBpXGVtcGxveWVlLW1hbmFnZW1lbnRcY3JlYXRlLWVtcGxveWVl?=

Comment: Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:56
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:45310
Origin:http://localhost:36192
Referer:http://localhost:36192/emp-management
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded

Comment: @GurramNavyasri have you checked: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412

Comment: Precondition Failed is due to the logic in my service i have thrown that error

Answer (score 0):

> same code i have tried with normal controller in same Solution , if i send single parameter values is passed to API controller.

This points to a CORS issue, because if you run 2 solutions with 2 different addresses e.g. `localhost:5000/` & `localhost:5001/`. From my experience this only happens in development.

.net core doc's on CORS:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors

Try this: to your ServicesConfiguration add

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                                .AllowAnyHeader()));
```

And  `app.UseCors("AllowAll");` in your Configure

Another thing I spotted is

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Post, headers: headers });
let emp = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

You are setting content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but passing a `JSON` object.

Comment: If i add content type as application/json it is not allowing to call API getting method not allowed

Comment: services.AddCors( this should be added to the project from which my call is done or set in the service where my APIController is?

Comment: @GurramNavyasri on your API

Comment: to my knowledge CORS is used to allow any type of headers,origin,methods. if any of this doesn't satisfy then my API will not be called. But here my API is called but values are becoming null in my object.

Comment: @GurramNavyasri I would take a look at the content type, and the object that is being passed. Try to test it with postman.

Comment: I have tested through fiddler my API is working fine

Comment: Content-Type: application/json

Comment: Thank you so much. i have gone through CORS concepts. i got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

WebApiConfig.cs

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
```

and my content type as

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' });
```

It works...